# form angular loading without appearance, and without erros

Tags: angular-material, modal-dialog, angular-reactive-forms, angular13, appearance

All Forms of my application load without applying the theme (Appearance), I already tried solutions like adding @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in my style.scss and also checked the module imports, are OK!
I use Angular 13

I'm using vex theme

When I open localhost:4200 on the screen that opens the modal, it works normally, but if I change the route and then return, the inputs stop appearing, no error is shown

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'vex-cadastrar-editar-servico',
    templateUrl: './cadastrar-editar-servico.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cadastrar-editar-servico.component.scss']
})
export class CadastrarEditarServicoComponent {
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            nome: ['', Validators.required],
            tempo: ['', Validators.required],
            categoria: ['', Validators.required],
            valor: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <!-- Titulo do modal -->
    <div
        class="px-6 py-4 border-b"
        id="title"
        fxLayout="row"
        fxLayoutAlign="start center"
    >
        <h2 class="title m-0">Novo Serviço</h2>
    </div>

    <!-- modal -->
    <mat-dialog-content>
        <div [formGroup]="form" class="example-form">
            <!-- Nome do servico -->
            <div class="nome">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" id="inpN">
                    <mat-label class="nome">Nome do serviço</mat-label>
                    <input formControlName="nome" matInput required />
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('nome').hasError('required')">
                        Preencha este campo!
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <!-- Tempo estimado -->
            <div class="tempoEs">
                <mat-form-field id="tempoEst">
                    <mat-label>Tempo Estimado</mat-label>
                    <input
                        formControlName="tempo"
                        type="text"
                        matInput
                        placeholder="Digite o Tempo"
                        maxlength="3"
                        required
                    />
                    <span matTextPrefix class="minutos">Minutos&nbsp;</span>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('tempo').hasError('required')">
                        Preencha este campo!
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <!-- Categoria -->
                <mat-form-field id="categoria">
                    <mat-label>Categoria</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="categoria" required>
                        <mat-option value="option">Cabelo</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="option">Barba</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                    <mat-error
                        *ngIf="form.get('categoria').hasError('required')"
                    >
                        Selecione uma opção!
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <!-- area de descricao -->
            <div class="descricao">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" id="descricao">
                    <mat-label>Descrição do serviço</mat-label>
                    <input
                        matInput
                        placeholder="Ex. Tipo de corte, tipo de barba..."
                    />
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <!-- toggle de valor promocional -->
            <div class="toggle">
                <mat-slide-toggle
                    ><b
                        >Este serviço mostrará o valor promocional</b
                    ></mat-slide-toggle
                >
            </div>

            <!-- valor e valor promocional -->
            <div class="valor">
                <mat-form-field floatLabel="always" class="intval">
                    <mat-label>Valor</mat-label>
                    <span matTextPrefix>R$&nbsp;</span>
                    <input
                        formControlName="valor"
                        id="valor"
                        matInput
                        type="number"
                        class="example-right-align"
                        placeholder="0"
                    />
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('valor').hasError('required')">
                        Preencha este campo!
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <!-- valor promocional -->
                <mat-form-field floatLabel="always" class="intval">
                    <mat-label>Valor Promocional</mat-label>
                    <span matTextPrefix>R$&nbsp;</span>
                    <input
                        formControlName="valor"
                        id="valorP"
                        matInput
                        type="number"
                        class="example-right-align"
                        placeholder="0"
                    />
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('valor').hasError('required')">
                        Preencha este campo!
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-dialog-content>

    <!-- botoes adicionar e cancelar -->
    <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
        <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancelar</button>
        <button
            mat-button
            [mat-dialog-close]="true"
            mat-raised-button
            color="primary"
        >
            Adicionar
        </button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^13.0.2",
    "@iconify/icons-emojione": "~1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-fa-brands": "~1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-fa-solid": "^1.1.1",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.1.6",
    "@iconify/icons-logos": "^1.1.10",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "~9.0.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^5.1.2",
    "@visurel/iconify-angular": "~11.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "~0.29.0-beta.10",
    "apexcharts": "~3.25.0",
    "date-fns": "~2.19.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "highlight.js": "~10.6.0",
    "luxon": "~1.26.0",
    "ngx-quicklink": "~0.2.7",
    "ngx-quill": "~16.0.1",
    "ngx-showdown": "~6.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "quill": "~1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "showdown": "~1.9.1",
    "simplebar": "~5.3.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
}
```

[When load page, and open dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3VjO.png)

[when navigate to another route, and retry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thGmi.png)